# msvc2010 - how to build a clean output directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm having problem with visual studio 2010 because it now makes my output directory full of .pdb and other files when building.

In previous version of msvc I had intermediate directory set to something else than the output dir and had the .pdb files (and everything else basically) generated there: $(IntDir)/$(ProjectName).pdb say.

Now, in new version of msvc, it seems to still build the .pdb there but, for a reason I don't know, also put a .pdb file in my output dir (which I don't want). Same thing seems to happen for .ilk files if I set incremental linking but that is less important as I can just disable incremental linking but .pdb is essential to debug the program.

I think this is a bug in msvc but I only found this on connect.microsoft.com:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/538348/targetpath-bug which seems to be the same problem as me but the way he set the parameter this is not a bug. The way my config is done, it would be a bug but before filing one I would like to know if anyone had that issue and if they found a way to fix it (ie is it really a bug).

Basically, just create a project with a different Intermediate directory and specify the pdb to be build there. Vs2010 seems to still create a .pdb in Output directory.

I guess for now I could add a post-build event to copy the executable.

Is anyone had the same problem?

Have you found a solution?

Is there a better way to get a clean output directory for now using msvs2010?

Comment: Did you try to rename pdb file using `Program Database File Name` property (in the Output Files page)?

Comment: I think it's actually the setting on the "Debugging" tab of the "Linker" settings that needs changing.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to be possible via setting project properties. The only property that could do the job is  [`/Fd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wst99a9.aspx) (`Program Database File Name` property), but it works only for the PDB related to individual OBJ files.

So I guess to stay with the post-build event...