# Configure VS2010 to build a C++ project to a reasonably clean output directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In VS2010 a one line hello world C++ console program using the default project configuration outputs over 30 files of intermediate build files to its output directory. Obj files, pch files, ilk, log, buildstate, idb, embedded manifest and rc files and no less than 18 tlog files.

None of this is actually output, for an exe console app the only files which are genuine output are the exe itself and the pdb file.

So my question is this: Is there any way to configure VS2010 to build all this garbage into an intermediate directory and output just the useful stuff to the output directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970918/msvc2010-how-to-build-a-clean-output-directory

Comment: It already does this:  If you create a new C++ Console Application project in Visual Studio 2010 and build it, the build outputs to two places:  $(ProjectDir)\$(Configuration), which has the intermediate build files, and $(SolutionDir)\$(Configuration), which has three files:  the .exe, the .pdb, and a .ilk that the linker requires for incremental linking (if you disable incremental linking, this file will not be built).  How is this behavior different from what you are asking for?

Comment: If you don't have a separate directory for the solution (and if the solution is only one project why would you) it instead just dumps everything directly to the output directory. That said it is still interesting to know that if you have a separate directory for the solution it behaves more sensibly so thanks for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio, open the Solution Explorer, right-click the project and select Properties...  In the Property Pages dialog, navigate to Configuration Properties -> General.  The first two properties control where the build output goes:

- **Output Directory**:  This is the directory into which the final build output (.exe, .pdb, .ilk) is placed
- **Intermediate Directory**:  This is the directory into which (most) everything else is placed.

If you use the typical project layout, where the project is in a folder under the solution folder, these properties will be configured so that the two directories are different.  You can, of course, configure them to place the output wherever you'd like.

Comment: I use this technique, and I further define Intermediate to be `%TEMP%\$(SolutionName)\$(ProjectName)\$(ConfigurationName)` -- this gets the OBJs et al entirely out of the source tree.

Comment: @MikeC - nice trick, but don't you mean: $(TEMP)\$(SolutionName)\$(ProjectName)\$(ConfigurationName)?

Comment: @bavaza - if %TEMP% does not work, then yes, you must be right; I'm no longer working where I had that set up, and so cannot check.

Answer (score 1):

you can go to :

Project->Properties->Build Event-> Pre-Build Event Commandline

Project->Properties->Build Event-> Post-Build Event Commandline

here you can commandline script for all of your cleaning or copying ans so on.

Comment: Nice suggestion but it would be tiresome to do all of it manually.

Comment: Yes but again it would be cool if there is something like a hidden feature in VS to delete all these files after the build completes.